# Make QTableWidget columns expand up to and stop expanding at specific width

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to customize a QTableWidget in a specific way, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. I want the QTableWidget, when it is expanded, to expand according to the following rules:

1. All columns will expand equally, much like the functionality of the [`setResizeMode`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode)`(QHeaderView.Stretch)`
2. However, once the columns reach a specific width, I want all the columns to expand to a maximum width (say 150 pixels) and the rest of the space give to the last column, much like the functionality of [`setStretchLastSection(True)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#setStretchLastSection)

Shrinking the table backwards should follow the rules in reverse.

I've tried overriding the resizeEvent for the QTableWidget, but that doesn't seem to work, especially when `setResizeMode` and `setStretchLastSection` are used. Do I have to update the QHeaderView instead? How do I achieve this?

---

I've got a class where I've tried to implement this. It works, but only after the table size has been updated. The process of displaying the table messes with the size and I have to update the size myself to have it reapply the resizing properties I want.

```
class DataTable(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, data, header):
        # Call the super class method
        super().__init__(6,4) # Make if 6 rows by 4 columns for this example

        # Put the data in the table
        # Removed from MWE

        # Configure the table properties
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        #self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.horizontalHeader().length()+self.verticalHeader().width())#, self.verticalHeader().length() + self.horizontalHeader().height())


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if self.columnWidth(3) > 100: # 3 is the last column in this MWE
            for i in range(3):
                self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView.Fixed)
            self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(3,QHeaderView.Stretch)
        else:
            for i in range(3):
                self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(i,QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(3,QHeaderView.Stretch)

        super().resizeEvent(event)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of **Shrinking the table backwards should follow the rules in reverse.**?

Comment: I mean that if the user shrinks the table instead of expanding it, only the last column should shrink, until is the same width as the other columns, at which point all columns should continue to shrink proportionally together.

Comment: PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Comment: PyQt4 if possible.